# Why does rails require JavaScript Runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was installing rails(v3) on my Ubuntu Linux Box & the install failed complaining of missing javascript runtime. I did some lookup & it turns out that rails require a javascript runtime to be installed on the platform its running.

While, Windows has come bundled with jscript by default. My Ubuntu box didn't have a js runtime & I fixed the issue by installing node.js(V8).

AFAIK, a js runtime is required to execute javascript code & rails is just a web framework in which javascript are embedded. Javascript files run only on client machines.

So,
**Why does rails require JavaScript Runtime?**

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Probably for CoffeeScript, if I had to guess.

Comment: There's an answer but I agree this is kind of illogical and annoying of rails. But whatever.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Look into the [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). It does fancy stuff with JavaScript (and CSS) files. Notably:

1. It converts CoffeeScript into JavaScript
2. It combines all javascript files into one
3. It minifies that file

The JavaScript runtime is [used for minification](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-compression).

Comment: @David天宇Wong it depends on if you compile your assets in production or development

Comment: It's worth noting, that processing JavaScript (without executing it) would *not principally* require a JavaScript runtime. The reason why the Rails asset pipeline needs a JavaScript runtime is that it does the processing with tools like CoffeeScript and uglifier that *themselves are implemented in JavaScript* and which thus require a runtime to be used.

Comment: As often, best answer in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Railsguides says it has to do with compression:

> You will need an ExecJS supported runtime in order to use uglifier. If you are using Mac OS X or Windows you have a JavaScript runtime installed in your operating system. Check the ExecJS documentation for information on all of the supported JavaScript runtimes.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-compression

I thought I had seen Rails actually check the validity of both the stylesheets and the javascript in your app, but maybe it was just SASS prepreocessing.

Comment: Yeah probably SASS; Just like CoffeeScript SASS is default for every pre created stylesheet file in /assets/stylesheets and you can write straight CSS in them without even realising.