# Why does Rails say it cannot find a JavaScript runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working through "[Getting started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)."

After creating the blog I got this error when I run `rails server`:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in "autodetect":
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. 
See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable
```

I added the 'execjs' gem to my Gemfile, but still got the same error. I reinstalled RVM, then reinstalled the gem, and all that I thought to solve the problem.

Comment: Try adding also 'therubyracer'.

Comment: i did it, but thx. is in execjs folder, like rubyrhino

Comment: As a hint for writing useful questions that attract answers, try turning on your spelling checker, and correct spelling and punctuation mistakes. While it's understandable that errors will creep in if English isn't your native language, spelling and grammar checkers exist that can do quite a credible job of fixing problems. It's well known on Stack Overflow that a well written question will gather a lot more answers than one that is difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [node.js](http://nodejs.org).

Check "[Why does rails require JavaScript Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673081/why-does-rails-require-javascript-runtime)."

Comment: i downloaded it, but im not sure how to install node. the decompresed folder is allocated in mi `home` folder. I opened the readme file with an editor but im not sure how to run `./configure` and follow the next step. Is enought with save node in home folder? i must build anything?

Comment: Are you using os x (there is a auto install .pkg) or using ubuntu ( `sudo apt-get install nodejs` )

Comment: Thanks, I'll start again. Start by re-reading the documentation you find on rvm, ruby node ... this will take long.
So as I have no intention of torturing anyone with my probing questions, give your answer for good.
Thanks anyway for your indications. True, I use Unix recently and I'm quite lost yet. But you know what they say: the best way to learn is to experiment.
A greeting.