# Can Rails be used without a JavaScript runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

By default, Rails requires a JavaScript runtime. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674413/3994388) for why.)

**Is it possible to configure a Rails application so it doesn't have this requirement?** If so, what restrictions (e.g., can't use CoffeeScript, won't uglify delivered JavaScript, ...) would this impose on the application?

Is the asset pipeline the only part of Rails that requires a Javascript runtime, or are there others?

(I don't have a use-case where this would be required. I'm merely wondering whether it can be done, and if so, how cleanly.)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea whether this would do the trick, but I wonder if [disabling the asset pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22572193/877472) would do this. I don't know whether this is the only portion of rails the requires a JS runtime, but you could try this method (I cannot presently), get rid of the v8 engine and all that and see what happens (hypothetically).